# PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.REQUEST_DATETIME' Issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to write a Trigger which basically updates one table when an entry is made on another table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DTISCDB_OWNER"."REQUEST_CONTEXT_TR" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON REQUEST_CONTEXT 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:NEW.REQUEST_DATETIME := SYSDATE;
:NEW.ID := TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(100000000000000000000000000000000000,999999999999999999999999999999999999));
SELECT bre_conditions_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :OLD.seq_number FROM dual;
SELECT REQUEST_CONTEXT.CURRENT_STATE INTO :NEW.STATE FROM REQUEST_CONTEXT;
SELECT REQUEST_CONTEXT.REQUEST_ID INTO :NEW.REQUEST_ID FROM REQUEST_CONTEXT;

INSERT INTO REQUEST_LIFECYCLES(ID,SEQ_NUMBER,STATE,REQUEST_ID,REQUEST_DATETIME)
                        VALUES(:NEW.ID,:NEW.seq_number,:NEW.STATE,:NEW.REQUEST_ID,:NEW.REQUEST_DATETIME);
 END;
```

Comment: The error seems to imply that there is no `request_datetime` in `request_context`.  Is there?  Once you solve that, you can't change the `:old.seq_number` so that makes no sense.  You can't select from `request_context` .  And why would you generate a random number rather than just using a sequence to generate the `:new.id`?

Comment: Are you trying to use `:NEW` to refer to the columns in the table you're inserting into, rather than the table the trigger is against? You can just use `sysdate` directly in the `values` clause. The `:OLD` reference is still confusing though. You seem to be confused about what old and new represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what the [correlation pseudorows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) are for and what they hold and can do. It looks like you're treating `:NEW` as if it is related to the `REQUEST_LIFECYCLES` table you are inserting into inside the trigger, and `:OLD` as if it is related to the `REQUEST_CONTEXT` row that has been inserted or updated and caused the trigger to fire.

Both `OLD` and `NEW` refer to the table the trigger is against, `REQUEST_CONTEXT`. If the trigger was fired by an update then `OLD` has the pre-update values for the affected row; if it was fired by an insert then it is empty as there is no old state. Either way `NEW` has the current state, with the newly-inserted or post-update values. You can't change the `OLD` values, and it doesn't make sense to change the `NEW` values in an 'after' trigger. You also don't need to query the table the trigger is fired against, as the `NEW` pseudorow already makes that information available.

So if you are trying to use the inserted/updated values in `REQUEST_CONTEXT` to create a row in `REQUEST_LIFECYCLES`, you would do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DTISCDB_OWNER"."REQUEST_CONTEXT_TR" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON REQUEST_CONTEXT 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO REQUEST_LIFECYCLES(ID, SEQ_NUMBER, STATE, REQUEST_ID,
    REQUEST_DATETIME)
  VALUES(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(100000000000000000000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999999999999999999)),
    bre_conditions_seq.NEXTVAL, :NEW.CURRENT_STATE, :NEW.REQUEST_ID,SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

I'm assuming you wanted to set the 'lifecycle' `SEQ_NUMBER` value from the trigger, despite you trying to set the `:OLD` value - hopefully the old reference was a mistake. If you were trying to set that value in both `REQUEST_CONTEXT` and `REQUEST_LIFECYCLES` you would need a before insert/update trigger instead, and would set `:NEW.SEQ_NUMBER` rather than the `:OLD` value, before using it in the `values` clause.

As Justin said using a random value for the ID is rather strange, not least because it won't be unique, and a sequence is much more common. You may actually want the ID from the inserted/updated row, in which case you can just refer to `:NEW.ID` in the values clause instead of generating a new value. (It's also possible you are trying to *set* that ID in both `REQUEST_CONTEXT` and `REQUEST_LIFECYCLES` too, but that would be even stranger, and you'd need a before-insert/update trigger to do that anyway).